# Cannot login after resuming from sleep

Tags: windows, windows-8, login, sleep

I am using Windows 8 64bit. My computer is Toshiba R830.

I have found that when I make the computer sleep and resume from sleep, I cannot login using the password. Having resumed from sleep, at the login page, the computer has no response when I press Enter. No response at all, no error information, or no prompt about incorrect password.

Now my temporary solution is that: I sleep the machine AGAIN, and awake it, and then it shows the desktop directly without asking for password

I hope there are some experts helping me out. Thanks : )